# Slow/Poor Performance on SSIS with xml

Tags: xml, ssis

I'm new to SSIS and I got this problem:

I've a little over 100.000 xml-files, each of them around 16kb big. They have about 200 columns and one primary key. Some of them are only for update.
I've to fill a database with the data, but it takes about 1,5 second for each file to load/update. I'm using VS 2015 and MS SQL.
I only want to create the database within working hours, right now it would take about 44 hours, which seems ridiculous. (After that there will be only about 10 xml-files per day for updating.)

My SSIS ControlFlow looks like:

[image]

My SSIS DataFlow looks like: [image]

I've no idea how to get the performance better.

Things I tried:
Setting Ole DB = Rows per batch 5000 and use fast load

Even when I do only insert the xml (which ends in an error as I do not update), it needs a lot time (about 1 second per file).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the caching options on your Lookup transform: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141821.aspx Often, it will cache an enormous tabl (taking forever) and only use a fraction of it, or vise versa.

Comment: My Lookup did a full cache, changed it to no cache, but the time is still the same.

Comment: Honestly, doing 100,000 reads on very small files comes with a significant overhead. I'm afraid you're stuck with this situation as-is... Doing file i/o is slow.

Comment: Seems like I've to write a program to filter the latest updates and then insert only them...
Hoped there would be a simple thinking mistake or a magic trick ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just been doing something similar and am finding the same issue with overheads. I thought I would share my only work around - parallel processing.

So first work out how many cores your server has available. Rule of thumb is that you can have one process per core.

Then you can make an inbox folder for each core your machine has (assuming you have four cores):

- inbox 1
- inbox 2
- inbox 3
- inbox 4

Then go into your SSIS where you have your foreach loop in the Control Flow and copy this process four times, but don't connect them (this way they run individually).

Finally go into each foreach loop and edit each one so it picks up from a different inbox.

You need to obviously cut and paste your files into each inbox, but it will run four dataflows that do the same thing in parallel. i.e. You should load four files in the same time it used to take to load one.